# Pulling Data From Google Sheets Master List That is Continually Updated into Individual Child Sheets Based On The Named Row

Tags: google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NaitV2fKbceMRuR6CTd-QHDhqVpvwphG5G3sdEPz5_4/edit?usp=sharing

Above is a link to the Google Sheet that I am referencing.

I have a Google Sheets Master List, (first tab) called Master Prospect List.  This list will continuously be updated with data from different companies and will be assigned to 4 individuals currently, in the order on the master form, column B, as the new data is added.  I want to have the data pulled from the master list, as this new data is added to the master sheet, based on each individuals name, and have that data populate in each individuals own child sheet.  I have populated the 4 named individuals on the master already, however I'm not sure if that is the proper way to do it.  I When the data is added into the master, I want the date and time that the data was added to populate in column A.  I want all of the same columns to be added to the child sheets that are also on the master sheet.  I would as o like to have 4 separate colors alternating for the 4 individuals, instead of just 2 alternating , so that each individual would have their own color in their designated row on  the master list.  I don't think that is necessary on the child sheets.  I would also like to have a drop down list for telephone country codes in the country code column.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the **"QUERY"** formula.

> =QUERY('Master Prospect List'!A:P, "where (B = 'Sales Person Name')",1)

**Note:**

- This formula will return the data for **"Sales Person Name"** including the header row (row 1).
- You can re-arrange the column order by changing the query string.
- Use the same formula in all other tabs only change the "Sales Person Name"

Comment: THANKS FOR THE QUICK RESPONSE.  Do I have to add the column names from the master sheet, onto the child sheets, or will they auto-populate on the child sheets from the formula.  Also, where do I add this formula.  Do I add it to each child sheet, and just change the Sales Persons name in the formula. What cell do I put the formula in?  And what about the four different alternating colors for the individuals named on the master list and the drop down for the country codes for the phone numbers.  Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Write this column in each child sheet. You can write it in "A1", then row 1 will be the header.
2. You don't need to write the column name. Just the exact formula with the child's name. I mean write this formula in the "A1" cell in the "Harvey McGehee" sheet:

**=QUERY('Master Prospect List'!A:P, "where (B = 'Harvey McGehee')",1)**

Comment: Note: I can also write the column name if you want to change the column order or add more conditions in the filter.
For example, we add only one condition here: "where (B = 'Harvey McGehee')".
You can search more about query strings in google and get a clear idea.

Comment: @AmirHossain, I've been using this method, but is there a way to edit the child sheet then the update will be reflected to the master sheet... whenever you edit the child sheet, the data gets erased  and then an  error in the formula saying the data cannot be overwitten